# console.log not working when in $(document).ready(function()

Tags: jquery, wordpress, console.log

Haven't been working with jQuery for a long time. Now, with a fresh new project, I have a somehow strange behaviour.

The scripts are loaded in the correct order:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
some other scripts...

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://example.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/myscript.js?ver=4.9.7'></script>
```

`myscript.js`

```
(function ($) {
    console.log('logA');
    console.log($.fn.jquery);
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log('logB');
        console.log($.fn.jquery);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

With this code, I'd expect two log outputs:

`logA`
`1.12.4`

`logB`
`1.12.4`

But instead I only get `logA` `1.12.4` as output.

`logB` is not shown in the console, although I can access DOM-elements with `$('#elem, .elem2')`.

What's wrong here?

I also tried without the anonymous function, which gives me an error `$ is not a function`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      console.log('logB');
 });
```

jQuery-version: 1.12.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through the comments, after a point made by @Rup, it appears that something in the script is overriding the `console.log` method so that it does not print to the console any more.  To overcome this issue within the scope of your script, you can pass the console.log method into your IIFE, so that it retains the original function that log was assigned.

```
(function ($, log) {
    log('logA');
    log($.fn.jquery);
    $(document).ready(function(){
        log('logB');
        log($.fn.jquery);
    });
})(jQuery, console.log);
```

Comment: And, in this particular case, there's some obfuscated code in `/wp-content/themes/wpresidence/js/google_js/oms.min.js` that is assigning `function () {}` to `console.log`, specifically this statement: `_0xe5a60b[_0xaf69('0x4')] = _0x4b057f;`

Comment: FWIW, you probably want to pass in the whole `console` object, so you'll have access to its other methods as well - and, it'll keep your code more readable since you'll be able to write `console.log(...)` in your callback to make it clear which `log()` function you're invoking.

Comment: @dossy unfortunatelly, passing the whole console object doesn't work

Comment: Passing in the object didn't work, because the whole object was not being overridden.  Just the log method, it appears. @dossy

Comment: I suppose you could pass in a deep copy of the `console` object, replacing the last line with `})(jQuery, Object.assign(console));`

Comment: @dossy nope... Object.assign(console) still doesn't work

Comment: @ad_on_is Interesting, maybe it needs to be `Object.assign({}, console)` then.  Yup, just tested - that should trigger the deep copy.

Answer (score -4):

Check whether your jQuery file working properly, because I tried it, but it was working properly with the version you mentioned